# How do I, in an array, change state of 'text' depending on matching 'id'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects stored in state, each object representing an ingredient row. Rows will expand as required by user with a button, hence the map function on initial array.

I can get the ID of the row the user is interacting with, but how do I then change the state of the item? I've attempted `[name]:value` after the object spread to no avail.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    rows: [
      {
        id: 0,
        text: "",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "",
      },
    ],
  });

  function handleChange(id, value) {
    setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedRows = prevState.rows.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          console.log(item);
          return {
            ...item,
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
      console.log(id);
      return {
        rows: updatedRows,
      };
    });
  }

  const rowList = state.rows.map((item) => (
    <Row
      key={item.id}
      item={item}
      value={item.text}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  ));

  return <div> {rowList} </div>;
}

function Row(props) {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id, props.item.text)}
      placeholder="Some text"
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to pass on the value from `e.target.value` from handleChange like `onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(props.item.id, e.target.value)}`

and use it in state update

```
setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedRows = prevState.rows.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            text: value   // using the passed value
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
      console.log(id);
      return {
        rows: updatedRows,
      };
    });
```

Full Code

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    rows: [
      {
        id: 0,
        text: "",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "",
      },
    ],
  });

  function handleChange(id, value) {
    setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedRows = prevState.rows.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          console.log(item);
          return {
            ...item,
            text: value
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
      console.log(id);
      return {
        rows: updatedRows,
      };
    });
  }

  const rowList = state.rows.map((item) => (
    <Row
      key={item.id}
      item={item}
      value={item.text}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  ));

  return <div> {rowList} </div>;
}

function Row(props) {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={props.item.text}
      onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(props.item.id, e.target.value)}
      placeholder="Some text"
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, I literally had the same, just forgetting to pass the event. Thank you kindly!